# token is not created in nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, token

I have a function that selects username from mysql database and return results to post request as following:

```
function userAuthentication(user){
var deferred = Q.defer();
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        var dbError = new Error('No db connection');
        console.log(dbError);
    }
    else {
        var selectUserName = 'SELECT * FROM User WHERE username= '+connection.escape(user)+' ';

        connection.query(selectUserName, function(error, rows){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
            else if(rows.length === 0){
                var countError = new Error('No User Found');
                console.log ("Database.js -> "+ countError);
                deferred.reject(countError);
            }else{
                deferred.resolve(rows);
            }
        });
    }
    connection.release();
});
return deferred.promise;
```

}

the function `userAuthentication` is called from the rout.post request

```
router.post('/checkAuthentication', function(request, response) {

    database.userAuthentication(request.body.username).then(function(data) {
        if(data[0].RowDataPacket!=0){
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(request.body.password,data[0].password)){
                var token = jwt.sign({
                   username: data[0].username,
                }, superSecret,{
                    expiresInMinutes: 1440
                });

                console.log(token);
                // return the information including token as JSON
                response.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Token Created',
                    token: token
                }); 
            }
            else{
                response.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong Password.' });
            }
        }else{
            response.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        }       
    });
});
```

i am trying to create a token when i check if inputed username and password matches the ones in mysqlDb, but unfortunately the token is not created; the line `console.log(token)` is not printing any result into the console. what is the part i am missing??? I appreciate your help guys.

Comment: You say " the line `console.log(token)` is not printing any result into the console": what does taht mean, exactly? Is console.log statement not even executed? If it is, does it print an empty string, null, undefined... ?

Comment: @MarcoS u right i treated the var token as a variable.. how to i check in the console if token is created? because even the next lines, response.json are not fetching??

Comment: Is `console.log(token)` statement not even executed? If it is, what exactly does it print?

Comment: nothing is coming out to the console

Comment: So it is not executed. You should try to debug the code flow, then... For example adding a `console.log('calling jwt.sign()')` statement just before the call to `jwt.sign()`, and so on...

Comment: i tried it the problem is in this code where i write jwt.sign(), before this statement everything is good but not after.. @MarcoS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `jwt` node module are you using?
I suppose it is not [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken), since it does not support `expiresInMinutes`, but only `expiresInMinutes`...

However, you should enclose the `jwt.sign()` call in a try/catch block, to catch any error it throws...:

```
try {
  var token = jwt.sign(
    {
      username: data[0].username,
    },
    superSecret,
    {
      expiresIn: 1440 * 60,
    }
  );
} catch(err) {
  console.error('error signing json web token:', err);
}
```

Comment: var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken') this one, jsonwebtoken

Comment: See my updated answer: try using a try/catch block, and use `expiresIn` instead of `expiresInMinutes`...

Comment: Effectively, I don't see any `superSecret` definition, in your controller... :-(

Comment: just a dump question :$ 1440 * 60 its going to expire in 24h?

Comment: Yes, I did only convert 1440 minutes to seconds... You could also use "1 day", or the like, since `expiresIn` is `rauchg/ms.js` format (see https://github.com/rauchg/ms.js)...

Comment: yeah i saw it now in the documentation... thank you again :)